# Sorting MongoDB subfield throws exception on Java

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, cursor

I struggle with the problem. My code throws the exception on `cursor.hasNext();`

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("DBname");
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("ColName");
DBObject orderBy = new BasicDBObject();
orderBy.put("'field.subfield1.subfield2'", -1);
DBCursor cursor = coll.find().sort(orderBy);
...
cursor.hasNext();
```

The exception:
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException: Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33571128 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes

When I use similar query in the db console it works just fine. When I add search query it won't throw the exception and it won't return any result neither.

What is wrong with the code? I just need cursor with sorted docs.

Comment: Index the field. But really show you you actual document structure. If this is an array in any form then this will not do what you think it might do.

Answer (score 0):

In general the error means you need to reduce the set of results, or use an index etc. to perform the sort:

> MongoDB will only return sorted results on fields without an index if
>   the combined size of all documents in the sort operation, plus a small
>   overhead, is less than 32 megabytes.
>   [Sorted Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Sorted-Documents)

** I noticed you have double quoted the sort in:`orderBy.put("'field.subfield1.subfield2'", -1);` so that could be the issue - theres no index available and its trying to sort the whole collection.

Comment: Is it the problem? All I need is just to get result in specific order through cursor. Is it really impossible if I need to do that with pretty massive collection?
I can do that through console though.
Quotes don't really make a difference. It doesn't work with it neigher without.

Comment: If it works in the console then the same query will work via a driver.